# Retrofit 2.0 post List<model> to server

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit 2.0 to send my ArrayList from server, but I always get one error. it's : Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $.
Server wait this type json:

```html
    Param "array":
[
    {"number": "required*", "name": "required*", "lastname": "", "email":""},
    {"number": "required*", "name": "required*", "lastname": "", "email":""},
    {"number": "required*", "name": "required*", "lastname": "", "email":""},
    ...
]
```

and user auth token in header.
To send my data, I'm using this code:

```
private void sendUserPhoneBook(String access_token) {
    UserPhoneBookData userPhoneBookData = new UserPhoneBookData(LoginActivity.this);
    ArrayList<PhoneContactModel> list = userPhoneBookData.getPhoneBook();

    Server service = retrofit.create(Server.class);
    Call<ArrayList<PhoneContactModel>> call = service.sendPhoneBookApi(access_token,list);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<PhoneContactModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<PhoneContactModel>> call, Response<ArrayList<PhoneContactModel>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                // запрос выполнился успешно, сервер вернул Status 200
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "-sendUserPhoneBook" + String.valueOf(response.code()));

            } else {
                // сервер вернул ошибку
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<PhoneContactModel>> call, Throwable t) {
            // ошибка во время выполнения запроса
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "-sendUserPhoneBookErr = " + t.getMessage());

        }
    });

}
```

PhoneContactModel.class looks like:

```
public class PhoneContactModel {
public String name;
public String email;
public String number;
public String lastname;


public PhoneContactModel(String name, String email, String phoneNumber,String lastname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.number = phoneNumber;
}..more
```

My Server.class have @POST looks like:

```
@POST("/api/import")
Call<ArrayList<PhoneContactModel>> sendPhoneBookApi(@Header("TOKEN") String token, @Body ArrayList<PhoneContactModel> list);
```

Help my please do it !
P.S.:sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

You need to encapsulate this array list. So create class

```
public class ImportRequest
{
    private ArrayList<PhoneContactModel> list;
    public ImportRequest(ArrayList<PhoneContactModel> list){
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

and use it as body:

```
@POST("/api/import")
Call<ArrayList<PhoneContactModel>> sendPhoneBookApi(@Header("TOKEN") String token, @Body ImportRequest request);
```

Comment: I do this & now get this error Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: can You show exact request and response body for that call to server?

Comment: {"array":[{"email":"test_user_1_email@test.test","name":"Test User 1","number":"+380 66 467 9680"},{"email":"test_user_email@test.test","name":"Test User 2","number":"+360994679572"}]}
it's my output json. 
in theory, I need to delete the string {"array": and put it in the array key field without it. the completion of which is waiting for the server